# ONLY Update table when there are rows and display what is updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, exists

I am updating a table based on some criteria. I need to only update the table when there are rows available for that criteria. Here is an example of my code:

```
IF EXIST (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.Product_ID = TableB.ProductID
WHERE TableA.ProductID = 143)

BEGIN

UPDATE TableA
SET A.ProductID = 123
FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ProductID = Table.ProductID
WHERE TableA.ProductID = 143

END
```

ISSUE: Table updates the data but it seems to update everything every time I run instead of only updating when there are records. For example, when I run above query, I get `(10 row(s) affected)` message, when I run again, I should get `(0 row(s) affected)` because table has already been updated and IF statement should not get any results.

I tried the following option as well:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB 
ON TableA.Product_ID = TableB.ProductID 
WHERE TableA.ProductID = 143) >0

BEGIN

UPDATE TableA
SET A.ProductID = 123
FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ProductID = Table.ProductID
WHERE TableA.ProductID = 143

END
```

ISSUE: The above query only returns `Command(s) completed successfully`. I need the number of rows being updated as a result. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Is there any row in TableB with ProductID=123?

Comment: @@ROWCOUNT seems to be what you are looking for, but I'm not sure why you'd expect the second run of your first command to not update anything...

Comment: What happen if you just run this: "UPDATE A
SET ProductID = 123
FROM TableA A INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.ProductID = B.ProductID AND B.ProductID <> 123;"

Comment: The reason is because IF EXIST should not return anything because I am selecting from the same table that I have updated. If it's already been updated, there should be 0 records for the select statement and there are. That part works fine. I just found a solution. Within IF EXIST statement, I was selecting COUNT(*) which returns 0 as a result but it does have a result so therefore it updates the records again. This still doesn't give me the number of records updated though. I will look into @@rowcount. Thanks!

Comment: I have modified my query. I understand, it was confusing at first. I added a where clause. This the updated query, you can see that second run should not update anything because it doesn't exist.

Comment: It's not necessary to check if anything exists first. If nothing matches the `where` in the `UPDATE`..... then nothing gets updated. Even worse:  someone _might_ insert a valid row in between you checking and then not updating!

Answer (score 0):

If I guess what you want correctly, then this probably is a less convoluted way to do it.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE ProductID = 143)
BEGIN
UPDATE TableA
SET ProductID = 123
WHERE ProductID = 143;

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `COUNT(*)`.  Even if there are no rows, that will return a `0`, which does indeed exist *(always)*.  You simply need to replace it with `*`.

SQL Server's optimiser will then stop at the first record because of the `EXISTS` *(So potentially making it both faster And make it work)*.

The optimiser also know not to bother expanding the `*` because of the `EXISTS`.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
             FROM TableA
       INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Product_ID = TableB.ProductID
            WHERE TableA.ProductID = 143
          )
BEGIN

    <your update statement>;

    SELECT @@rowcount;  --  or "RETURN @@rowcount;" whatever is appropriate to your use case

END
```